# How to roll back impex import in Hybris

Tags: import, sap-commerce-cloud, impex, hotfolder

When any impex line fails, is it possible to roll back all the previously imported lines from the same impex file, and stop further execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hybris `Transaction` if you import Impex using the `ImpexService`

```
Transaction tx = Transaction.current();
tx.begin(); 
boolean success = false;
try
{
   // Import your impex here and catch exceptions that can occur
   doSomeBusinessLogic();
   success = true;
}
finally
{
   if( success )
      tx.commit();
   else
      tx.rollback();
}
```

You can find the hybris documentation here : https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c7387f186691014922080f2e053216a.html

Comment: Thank you. let me try this and get back if it is successful, as @mkysoft thinks it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Impex import not supported transaction, so rollback not possible. You need make custom development for rollback future with flex. On the other hand, updating/inserting items in transaction not feasible, because of thousand online user may be waiting on web site or service.

I suggest to develop inform mechanism for failed lines to support team.

If items can be synchronized, may be you can create temporary catalog for them and sync after success import.

Comment: Let me try the transaction once